# Error Jest with coverageReport a few lines are not covered by the tests

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm having problems with the coverageReport using jest. I have a project in nodejs 18 and using jest 29.5. When I run the unit tests and check the coverageReport there are a few inconsistencies in the report, for example, is shown line breaks in red or imports and comments as lines to cover, affecting my global coverage, those lines shouldn't appear in red or in yellow. Does anyone know why is this happening?

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz0mU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsxPG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH7Ha.png)

I've tried changing the jest version, also I've tried to use a different coverageProvider for jest but is not working as I expected. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your jest config and how you execute jest?

Comment: @pnts-se To execute jest I use the command npm run test. Here I posted the jest config because is to long for the comments: https://codepen.io/briancaldas93/pen/ZEqeXoY

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache?
`npx jest --clear-cache`

Or run:
`npx jest --no-cache --coverage`

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work for me.